# Automapper ProjectTo membersToExpand with filtering

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

As far as I know EF Core v5 supports filtering inside `.Include()` expression.
For example (I use dumb DB *just for testing* so there is no sense in entities)

```
var result = dbContext
    .Details
    .Include(e => e.Permissions
        .Where(p => p.UniqueId == Guid.Parse("DCADF7F5-5B86-4A6C-9C7F-6B3D4B55FF27")))
    .ToList();
```

That code produces SQL:

```
SELECT [d].[UniqueId], [d].[DetailsText], [t].[UniqueId], [t].[DetailsId], [t].[EmployeeID], [t].[PermissionDescription], [t].[PermissionName]
FROM [Details] AS [d]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [p].[UniqueId], [p].[DetailsId], [p].[EmployeeID], [p].[PermissionDescription], [p].[PermissionName]
    FROM [Permissions] AS [p]
    WHERE [p].[UniqueId] = 'dcadf7f5-5b86-4a6c-9c7f-6b3d4b55ff27'
) AS [t] ON [d].[UniqueId] = [t].[DetailsId]
ORDER BY [d].[UniqueId], [t].[UniqueId]
```

Here I see filer `WHERE [p].[UniqueId] = 'dcadf7f5-5b86-4a6c-9c7f-6b3d4b55ff27'`
But when I try to use like this:

```
var result = dbContext
    .Details
    .ProjectTo<DetailsDto>(
        mapper.ConfigurationProvider,
        i => i.Permissions
            .Where(p => p.UniqueId == Guid.Parse("DCADF7F5-5B86-4A6C-9C7F-6B3D4B55FF27"))
    )
    .ToList();
```

I see this SQL:

```
SELECT [d].[DetailsText], [d].[UniqueId], [p].[DetailsId], [p].[EmployeeID], [p].[PermissionDescription], [p].[PermissionName], [p].[UniqueId]
FROM [Details] AS [d]
LEFT JOIN [Permissions] AS [p] ON [d].[UniqueId] = [p].[DetailsId]
ORDER BY [d].[UniqueId], [p].[UniqueId]
```

By specifying `membersToExpand`  I see correct join statement but no filter is applied.
Is there a way to filter included navigation properties via `ProjectTo` ?

Comment: The filtering is done in your `CreateMap`. The expand stuff is unrelated.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu ok thanks, so.. if I want to specify different filtering, by some condition, it will not be possible that way... okay

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu right... but parameterization is not complete way to specify different filters as it's possible with `.Include()` option. Seems that way only `.Select()` can be useful. Just hoped it's possible to avoid fully re-mapping by hands only for specifying filters (completely different filters) for navigation properties. Thank you

Comment: `Include` is useless with `ProjectTo`. You can write _any_ filter in a `MapFrom`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu If we set the filtering on the Mapping configuration it means that include filtering will be applied everywhere we have this mapping. In the scenario that we are using ProjectTo in multiple places but we need include filtering only in one of those how do we handle this?

Comment: Using parameters as in the link above. Worst case scenario, a `SkipFilter` parameter, but you can probably find smth better for your particular scenario.